# Calling third party API gives me error: 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: node.js, api, request, postman

When I call an API using postman it gives me success response but same code I tried with Node js app then it gives me  error like. SO am I making any mistake or error was on server side? I also tried with sample code that postman generates. but it also gives an error. for request I used `request-promise` and `request` both npm packages

> ```
> <html> <head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head> <body
> bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx</center> </body> </html>
> ```

sample code:

```
var options = { 
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://IPAdd/app/v1/device/mac/zz',
  headers: 
   {
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     authorization: 'Token '+ token },
  body: 
   { //body JSON},
  json: true,"rejectUnauthorized": false 
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to pass  `followAllRedirects: true,` with request object to follow all redirects

```
var options = { 
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'http://IPAdd/app/v1/device/mac/zz',
  headers: 
   {
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     authorization: 'Token '+ token },
  body: 
   { //body JSON},
  json: true,
  "rejectUnauthorized": false , 
  followAllRedirects: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (error) throw new Error(error);

console.log(body);
});
```